# Visit visa for British citizen who doesn't yet hold British passport

Tags: uk, passports, standard-visitor-visas

My son was born outside the UK and is British by descent through his father. We haven't applied for a British passport in his country of birth because we are leaving soon and the application process will take many months. Is it possible to apply for a visitor visa on his country of birth passport to visit the UK? Will they reject it on the basis that he is a British citizen?

Answer (score 4):

A visa cannot be issued to a British citizen with a right of abode to the UK.

However, an alternative to British passport is a certificate of entitlement of the right of abode, attached in a foreign passport: https://www.gov.uk/right-of-abode/apply-for-a-certificate-of-entitlement.
The processing is usually faster than the application of a British passport.

Comment: I am aware of this but it is quite expensive so I thought he may be able to enter another way. However you have confirmed that that's not possible so we will have to consider it.

Comment: I recently had this with our son. He is British by birth as his mother is British. We ended up getting a Certificate of Entitlement as it’s the only way other than a passport.

Comment: @RobertJ.Clegg Do you know for how long the certificate is valid for?

Comment: @saimda Valid until the passport expires

Comment: It’s not a visa. It’s valid until passport expires.